# Raising IndexError

Tags: class, exception, python-3.x

So I have a class Point, which is here:

```
 class Point:

     def __init__(self,x,y):
         self.x = x
         self.y = y
     def __getitem__(self,index):
        self.coords = (self.x, self.y)
        if type(index) != str or type(index) != int:
            raise IndexError
        if index == 'x':
            return self.x
        elif index == 'y':
            return self.y
        elif index == 0:
            return self.coords[index]
        elif index == 1:
            return self.coords[index]
```

I am supposed to raise IndexError if the type of the index is not a str or an int, but for some reason it does not work if I raise the exception at the beginning or the end of the function. Where should I raise the exception here?

Comment: Should your condition be (if type(index) != str and type(index) != int) ?? You should put it at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
if type(index) != str or type(index) != int:
```

If it's a string, it can't be an integer. Conversely, if it's an integer, it can't be a string.

Hence at least *one* of those sub-conditions will always be true, so `or`ing them will give true.

Think, I have a fruit and I want to know if it's neither a banana nor an apple.

```
fruit   not banana OR not apple  not banana AND not apple
------  -----------------------  ------------------------
apple        T or F -> T               T and F -> F
banana       F or T -> T               F and T -> F
orange       T or T -> T               T and T -> T
```

Instead of using `or`, you need:

```
if type(index) != str and type(index) != int:
```

---

As an aside, unless you *need* to store `coords` for some other piece of code, you can probably bypass that bit altogether, and make your code a little cleaner:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __getitem__(self,index):
        # Check type first.

        if type(index) != str and type(index) != int:
            raise IndexError

        # Return correct value for a correct index.

        if index == 'x' or index == 0:
            return self.x
        if index == 'y' or index == 1:
            return self.y

        # Index correct type but incorrect value.

        raise IndexError
```

That code has removed the (apparently) superfluous use of `coords`, fixed the type checking, "minimised" the `if` statements for clarity, and added a final exception for cases where the type of `index` may be right but its *value* is wrong (such as `'z'` or `42`).

Comment: @A.J., yes, you beat me by six seconds, I guess I'll have to hope it comes down to the _best_ answer rather than the fastest :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Best answer for being the most thorough :)

Comment: @paxdiablo, I may have beat you by six seconds, but yours *is* good :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` statement is awry. Try

```
if type(index) not in [str, int]
```

---

```
>>> index = {}
>>> type(index) not in [str, int]
True
>>> index = []
>>> type(index) not in [str, int]
True
>>> index = 0
>>> type(index) not in [str, int]
False
>>> index = '0'
>>> type(index) not in [str, int]
False
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write the check statement like this:

```
type(index) != str and type(index) != int:
```

Your current check is forever True whatever your index type is!